# Where to look for Vintage Cookbooks in Spanish?

Tags: cookbook, spanish-cuisine

I'm trying to find some vintage Cookbooks printed in Spanish from the 30's, 40's and 50's for a present. After many google searches I can only seem to find vintage Cookbook sites in English only. Likewise, the vintage book shops in town have nothing in other languages.

Would anyone know a good place to search? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for books that are from a specific country or just books in spanish from the time period?

Comment: If you're not in a spanish-speaking area, it's going to be much more difficult to find second-hand books in spanish.  I volunteer for the book sale at our local library, and when we get books in most foreign languages we tend to weed them as we can't easily sell them.  If you talk to the people that sell second-hand books and let them know you're interested in a particular category, they might be willing to keep an eye out for you, and let you know if they come across one.

Answer (score 3):

I collect vintage books (birding books, though) and I speak spanish; I usually find good results in **ebay.es**

I have checked for you on *cocina* books, and have found these:  http://www.ebay.es/sch/Otros-Libros-antiguos-/269/i.html?_nkw=cocina
the page is in spanish, so it conveniently filters books in spanish for you.

If you are interested in one of the books http://www.ebay.es/itm/DR-A-VANDER-COCINA-MODERNA-/230916243325?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_186&hash=item35c3ae3f7d
and want to proceed with a purchase, change the domain in the URL to **ebay.com** http://www.ebay.com/itm/DR-A-VANDER-COCINA-MODERNA-/230916243325?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_186&hash=item35c3ae3f7d and voilà!

other interesting sources,
http://www.uniliber.com/resultados.php?pc=cocina&orden=PA

http://www.iberlibro.com/libros/libros-cocina.shtml

**iberlibro.com** is the spanish version of **abebooks.com** 
so you might get similar results searching there and filtering for ***cocina*** and a *year range*

http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?kn=cocina&yrh=1950&yrl=1930

Answer (score 2):

What you need to be doing is searching in Spanish, I'm not a Spanish speaker but Google translations gives this result "libros de cocina de época" when I translate from "vintage cookbooks".

One of the first results is this page:http://www.iberlibro.com/libros/libros-cocina.shtml which again for a non-Spanish speaker is hard to understand but it looks to me like either a Spanish Ebay or Amazon.

Hope you find what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi there! OP is more likely to get a hit with "libros de cocina antiguos" than "de epoca", though granted your first result was also my first result :)

Comment: Thank you for the follow up, like I said I don't speak any Spanish and I know how easily Google translations get messed up.