# What are some established western cook books from 1920 - 1960?

Tags: cookbook

I'm looking for a book that would, preferably, have been written by a renowned chef; or a book that was a standard or staple for, say, French cuisine.

I'm looking to add to my bookshelf of classic cultural texts, and I cook very often, and such a book would be very useful to me.

The book can be from any culture, but one that has a translation in English.

Comment: I'm sorry but book recommendations aren't on topic here. There's tons of cookbooks out there and everyone has their favorites.

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/50412/67

Comment: France : [I Know How To Cook](https://www.amazon.com/Know-How-Cook-Ginette-Mathiot/dp/071485736X) ; Spain : [1080 Recipes](https://www.amazon.com/1080-Recipes-Simone-Ortega/dp/0714848360).  (they were also re-released as 'France: The Cookbook' and 'Spain: The Cookbook');  American : Fannie Farmer, Better Homes & Gardens, Women's Home Companion, Good Housekeeping, Betty Crocker

Comment: Hm, I'm not asking for favorites, or "best." I am asking for, effectively, which are the most established. If I said "who are the most famous scientists of all time," and you seriously couldn't say "Isaac Newton, Aristotle, Einstein, Feynman, etc," because it was "too broad," and didn't know what to do with yourself, then you're just being disingenuous. That's all there is to that. Thanks though.

Comment: @user31078 If you want to discuss this you're welcome to head over to [meta], but please refrain from making disparaging comments about members of the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Irma Rombauer published the iconic *The Joy of Cooking* in 1931. It’s more of a textbook than just a collection of recipes, with whole chapters dedicated to the ingredients. And elaborate kitchen techniques are explained in full. You can pretty much find any ingredient or recipe for any dish, I even think there’s a recipe for haggis! And subsequent editions of the book (the last edition was published in 2006 for the tome’s 75th anniversary) expanded the content greatly to include many ethnic cuisines. It’s a real treasure!

Julia Child published the Bible for French cuisine *Mastering the Art of French Cooking* in 1961. It is definitely not for the timid cook. But even if you never plan to make bouillabaisse or coq au vin, the book is a delightful read. Julia’s inimitable character shines through on every page.